# S3 Redirect with Cloudfront getting "Access Denied" error Message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to use an S3 bucket to redirect from one website to another.  The redirect from "http://example.com" works, but I can't get the redirect from "https://example.com", "http://www.example.com" or "https://www.example.com" to work.

I have an S3 bucket called "example.com".  I then created a Cloudfront distribution, attached the custom SSL certificate, and added "example.com" and "www.example.com" as Alternate Domain Names.

I'm getting this access denied message:
[image]

I'm assuming that I am not doing something correctly on the policy settings for the S3 bucket.  Any guidance?

I am using the following bucket policy:
[image]

I am not currently using the "Access Control List".

Comment: What is your current CloudFront origin setup with S3? have you configured with S3 public access or with OAI/OAC? Please provide the S3 bucket policy if you have setup also

Comment: Hi Binh, I updated my post with the bucket policy.  I have Origin Domain and Name as the S3 bucket.  I don't have OAI/OAC configured.

Answer (score 0):

For the Cloudfront Distribution redirection to https, it is necessary to configure ACM SSL certificates. provision a certificate exactly for the **subdomain.example.com** and use the same **alternate domain name** subdomain.example.com unless there would be an SSL handshake error.

[image]

- Select your Origin domain and path
- In the origin access **->** use Origin access control settings (recommended) **->** Origin access control **->** Create Control Settings **->** Copy the bucket policy from this screen and update it to your s3 bucket policy.

[image]

- Follow the behavior settings as follows: specify your Origin and origin groups

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation.  This helped get the bucket policy correct in the S3 bucket.  I was still running into the "AccessDenied" error message but when I copied the bucket website endpoint and pasted it in the Origin Domain, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are 2 approaches that you can setup CloudFront with S3.

1. Your S3 bucket is **public** accessible and CloudFront origin with S3 is public

- Ensure your S3 bucket does not having enabled **Block Public Access**
- Ensure your S3 bucket policy is having **Public Read Access**
- Ensure you can access your S3 bucket object publicly via your web-browser
- Ensure you have configured your CloudFront origin with S3 using **Public** mode

2. Your S3 bucket is **private** and CloudFront origin must be configured with access control

- Ensure your S3 bucket is having enabled **Block Public Access**
- Ensure your S3 bucket policy is added with correct policy.
- Ensure you have configured your CloudFront origin with S3 using one of **Access control** mode, such as OAC

For testing, you can try the **Public** approach, but for better secure, you can follow the approach from *Zeeshan* comment.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to make sure that the CloudFront has as origin domain the URL of the S3 bucket and not just the name. That might be a workaround, but at least you will not get the access denied. When choosing the bucket, you should have the option to select "Use Website Endpoint":

[image: CloudFront option]

Example:

YES:
[domain].s3-website-[zone].amazonaws.com

NO:
[domain].s3.[zone].amazonaws.com